# Where do I find Juju Design and Architecture documents?

Tags: juju

I do not have a global understanding for juju and JujuCharm. Could you provide some Docs which have some details or the abstract architecture for Juju?

Answer (score 1):

There is a general website with information [here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started) (Juju Charms documentation) but this does not cover any information on Juju itself.

There is detailed information on the juju [github](https://github.com/juju/juju/tree/develop/doc) that will cover more information about the architecture and some other topics as well.